# MySQL SELECT from two tables, replace ID's with usernames

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables like this:

```
TABLE: users
id  |  username
----------------
1   |  nick1
2   |  nick2

TABLE: messages
id  |  from  |  to  |  text
--------------------------------
1   |  1     |   2  |  Hi man!
2   |  2     |   1  |  Oh, hi.
```

So, i need SELECT code for replacing "from" and "to" with usernames.

I need SELECT code for my app withe replaced ID´s with usernames :).

Many thanks to all.

Comment: What you want to select ? All messages table but instead of from and to , their usernames ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the table `messages` two times with the table `users`:

```
SELECT
    m.id,
    u1.username,
    u2.username,
    m.text 
FROM
    messages AS m
INNER JOIN
    users AS u1 ON u1.id = m.from
INNER JOIN
    users AS u2 ON u2.id = m.to
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to join users table twice with  aliasses:

```
  select * from messages 
  join users ufrom on from = ufrom.id 
  join users uto on uto.id=to
```